# Don't know the meaning of these complex kanji

Tags: kanji

おはようございます！

Seeking for help. Don't know the meaning of those kanji (big white, in the top right corner and in the lower right corner. Any help will be appreciated! Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: It's apparently some Chinese content. (Ab)using Japanese の in Chinese text is a recent trend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to look for the surrounding text, but all I got were Taiwanese/Chinese sources.

In the end I managed to find out that the big white character (which is for the most part obstructed by the illustration) is「嘯」and it seems to exist in Japanese according to [kanji.jitenon.jp](https://kanji.jitenon.jp/kanjig/3305.html) and [jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%98%AF). Both seem to agree that it means **to roar**.

The bottom red text reads「紅蓮{ぐれん}の夢{ゆめ}」but I'm not sure what it translates to. 紅蓮 means bright red whereas 夢 means dream or dreams.

The top red text reads "1986" using financial numerals in Simplified Chinese as dROOOze pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Wow, you rock. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, but keep in mind that these 'pure translation' questions generally fall [outside of the scope of the Japanese.SE](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799).

Comment: The top right text says 1986 in Financial Characters (they’re also in Simplified Chinese which makes this a poor imitation of some sort)

Comment: Thanks @dROOOze, I'll update my answer!

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. Yes, I wonder why are those Characters combined like that? 1986 is also intriguing.

Comment: You might have more luck over at the [Chinese Language SE](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/).